# Reuse the result from subquery in Azure Stream Analytics Query

Tags: sql, azure, azure-stream-analytics

I am using Azure Stream Analytics and I am facing some problem on query part. Here is my codes.

```
WITH subquery as (
    SELECT 
    messageId,
    deviceId,
    temperature, 
    humidity,
    EventProcessedUtcTime,
    DemoML(temperature, humidity) as result1
    from DemoInput
    )

SELECT
    messageId as messageId,
    deviceId as deviceId,
    temperature as temperature,
    humidity as humidity,
    EventProcessedUtcTime as EventProcessedUtcTime,
    result1.[Scored Labels] as result,
    result1.[Scored Probabilities] as resultProbability
INTO
    [DemoOutput]
FROM
    [subquery]


SELECT
    result1
INTO
    [c2d]
FROM
    [subquery]
```

DemoML is a function where it will return the result. I want to put result1 into two different outputs. But I only managed to put result1 into one output. How can I achieve that? I am totally new to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `INSERT ... OUTPUT ... INTO ... SELECT` to insert twice:

```
WITH subquery as (
    SELECT 
    messageId,
    deviceId,
    temperature, 
    humidity,
    EventProcessedUtcTime,
    DemoML(temperature, humidity) as result1
    from DemoInput
    )
INSERT INTO target_1(col1,...)
OUTPUT inserted.col1, ...
INTO target_2(col1, ..)
SELECT
    messageId as messageId,
    deviceId as deviceId,
    temperature as temperature,
    humidity as humidity,
    EventProcessedUtcTime as EventProcessedUtcTime,
    result1.[Scored Labels] as result,
    result1.[Scored Probabilities] as resultProbability
FROM  [subquery];
```

Simplified:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(i INT);
CREATE TABLE t2(i INT);
CREATE TABLE src(i INT);
INSERT INTO src(i) VALUES(10),(20);

INSERT INTO t1(i)                 -- target one
OUTPUT inserted.i
INTO t2(i)                        -- target two
SELECT i
FROM src;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=dbd30328b71adb81b24c140b226a0436)**

Comment: In this case, am I putting same data into two different targets?

Comment: @SamTew Yes, just check demo link, but you could manipulate column lists if needed.

Comment: What if I want to put two different set of data into two table?

Comment: @SamTew Then you could use `INSERT over DML`  syntax. Your original question is solved.

Comment: Hi,
From the title, I see you want to do this in Azure Stream Analytics. In this case CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements are not supported.
Your initial query looks good and will have 2 different output. What issue do you see when you run it?

Comment: @JSAzure Hi. It looks good and no error when running but it wont trigger the Azure Function. FYI, c2d is the output to Azure Function. When I changed subquery to DemoInput, then it will trigger the function. So I suspect the problem lies on the query.

Comment: @SamTew The only difference I see here is the Azure ML call. Did you test it independently to be sure it returns some value?

Comment: @JSAzure I realize the my problem is the Azure function. The code in Azure function does not fit the input.

Comment: @JSAzure I asked the question in another post. Can you help me to take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604272/c-sharp-jsonconvert-deserializeanonymoustype-failed